# Please help me to fix my bread to be more soft and smaller hole

Tags: baking, bread

This is what happen last time [how to make dense texture bread?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42814/how-to-make-dense-texture-bread)

I follow what rumtscho said and went a bit out of the track. and this is my result: [image]

the hole is quite big which is not what I want. The process and recipe that I used for this you can read it below the rumtscho answer (the comment part of the answer). I knead it for 60 mins. anyone please help me achieve what I want.

I also tried the second recipe which is this one: http://wlteef.blogspot.com/2007/06/hokkaido-milk-loaf.html

and this is the result: [image]

it is still very far away from what I want which is this(the below one I bought it from bakery shop and this is what I want):
[image]

anyone please help me I feel something went really wrong.

Comment: Personally I think the second loaf you made is pretty damn identical in terms of crumb density to the shop-bought.

Comment: the shop-bought are softer and it has much smaller hole and the holes are evenly but the one I made is not. can anyone please give me suggestion

Comment: is it possible that the bakery shop use cake flour to make this? that why the texture are very evenly and soft with small hole?

Comment: This is the same question previously asked, just with more information added.

Comment: it's not duplicate.

Comment: It **is** a duplicate - it's literally the exact same question. You've even posted the same photo. That is why we allow (and encourage) people to edit their questions here. You never accepted an answer to the previous question which implies that it hasn't been answered yet, further reinforcing the conclusion that this is, in fact, just an extension to that question. If you have clarifications, failed recipe attempts, etc. to discuss - edit them into your previous question. We want people searching for techniques on making dense bread to find *one* authoritative Q&A on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The bakery is probably selling bread produced using the [Chorleywood process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorleywood_bread_process), which is a high-volume, high-speed process that uses low-protein flours and additional ingredients (emulsifiers, gums, enrichment) to produce bread that is very light and easy to slice compared to home-baked bread. It's challenging to replicate in a home kitchen, and there's good reasons not to try as home baked bread tends to taste better and may be better for you.

If you are getting really dense bread:

- you may be over-kneading. You said you kneaded for 60 minutes, which is far too long. I rarely ever knead more than 10 minutes. Over-kneaded bread has too much gluten developed, and will be tough
- it may be too dry. Much of the air in bread comes from water turning to steam, dry dough will end up with a close texture. Try adding more water and kneading with oil instead of flour
- It may be under-proofed. The yeast may be retarded by too much salt, not enough heat, or being too old. It may also be you just didn't leave it long enough. If you want a light and fluffy loaf let the first rise go until  trippled
- You may have knocked the dough back too much after the first rise. Many people beat the heck out of their bread after first rise, but this will undo much of the work the first rise did in creating air. Handle the dough gently when shaping and moving it into the baking pan, or you may end up losing your air